# NoSQL, Cassandra and Cloud databases

Tags: cassandra, nosql

- > NoSQL, Cassandra and Cloud databases use different approaches to guarantee validity of transactions
- > what are examples for that different approaches ?

Comment: This looks like an exam or homework question, is it?

Comment: @BradSchoening  yes

Comment: Also, questions should have a question mark (?) or two, to highlight what the actual questions are.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra uses **eventual consistency** and extends the concept with tunable consistency levels. The most common consistency level, and probably what most use cases should use is **quorum** consistency.

Quorum means a majority of the nodes agree on the data values being written or read. This provides strong read and write consistency and availability in the case of node failure.

[image]